# Cannot send email using CodeIgniter's email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email using CodeIgniter's email library. This is the code that I have written.

```
        $email_config = array(
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => ' ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => 'shamir.towsif@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '**********',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'newline'   => "\r\n",
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            "wordwrap" => true
        );

    $this->CI->load->library('email', $email_config);
    $this->CI->email->from('shamir.towsif@gmail.com', 'invoice');
    $this->CI->email->to('shamir.towsif@gmail.com', "User");
    $this->CI->email->subject('Invoice');
    $this->CI->email->message('Test');
    $this->CI->email->send();
    echo $this->CI->email->print_debugger();
```

**Error:** This is the error that I am getting.

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known Unable to send data:
>   AUTH LOGIN Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:  Unable to send
>   data: MAIL FROM: from:  The following SMTP error was encountered: 
>   Unable to send data: RCPT TO: to:  The following SMTP error was
>   encountered:  Unable to send data: DATA data:  The following SMTP
>   error was encountered:  Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter
>   Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2015 05:52:56 +0600 From: "invoice" Return-Path: To:
>   shamir.towsif@gmail.com Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Invoice?= Reply-To:
>   "shamir.towsif@gmail.com" X-Sender: shamir.towsif@gmail.com X-Mailer:
>   CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID:
>   <5585fcd8c63f7@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type:
>   multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b" This is a
>   multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not
>   support this format. --B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Test
>   --B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Test
>   --B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b-- Unable to send data: .
>
> The following SMTP error was encountered:  Unable to send email using
>   PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this
>   method. User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2015 05:52:56 +0600
>   From: "invoice"  Return-Path:
>    To: shamir.towsif@gmail.com Subject:
>   =?iso-8859-1?Q?Invoice?= Reply-To: "shamir.towsif@gmail.com"  X-Sender: shamir.towsif@gmail.com X-Mailer:
>   CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID:
>   <5585fcd8c63f7@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> Test
>
> --B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Test
>
> --B_ALT_5585fcd8c643b--

**Question:** I used to be able to send emails. Then I reinstalled my os and lamp server and now I cannot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try 'sendmail' ?

Comment: why are you suggesting another library?

Comment: I am not asking you to use another library, instead of smtp, try send mail. Just a matter of changing so e params in your config.

Comment: How can I use gmail then?

Comment: I will put it as an answer.

Comment: How can I use gmail then?

Comment: You are trying this in local machine or a hosting environment?

Comment: local machine, not hosting environment

Comment: What is the web serve you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use sendmail for email in CI. Before using send mail you have to do some configurations in CI.

First, go to system/libraries/Email.php and change the following

```
class CI_Email {

  var   $useragent      = "CodeIgniter";
  var   $mailpath       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"; // Sendmail path
  var   $protocol       = "sendmail";   // mail/sendmail/smtp
  var   $smtp_host      = "mail.blah-blah.com";     // SMTP Server.  


  .....
}
```

Then I make a method to send emails.

```
public function send_mail($email, $subject, $message){
        //$this->load->library( 'email' );
        $this->email->from( 'no-reply@blah-blah.com', 'blah-blah.com' );
        $this->email->to( $email);
        $this->email->subject( $subject );
        $this->email->message( $message );
        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();

    }
```

That's all. you can use the `send_mail` method to send emails now.

Comment: The line `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` will never execute due to the return statement above it. Better to check the success of the `send()` call, and then conditionally `return` or `print_debugger()` based on that.

Comment: @e_i_pi I don;t know how I missed that, Thanks for the pointer. I will edit.